# How to mock controller in integration test?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I would like to make an integration test (using `WebApplicationFactory`) that tests both my route configuration and serialization layer.

I want the test to (roughly) read like this:

```
var controllerSpy = new BooksControllerSpy(201);

var factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Startup>();

var client = factory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
             {
                 // ???? inject controllerSpy into controller registry
             }).CreateClient();

var response = await client.PostAsync(
                   "/api/books", 
                   new StringContent(@"{ ""name"": ""The Bible"" }")
               );

Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.Created, response.StatusCode);
Assert.Equal("The Bible", controllerSpy.DeserializedCommand.Name);
```

I'm wondering specifically how I might inject a controller into my test server's controller registry so I can focus my test on routing and serializing.

Thanks in advance for any ideas you have!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET Core MVC has an extension method on `IMvcBuilder` called `AddControllersAsServices` which enables the developer to register controllers inside `IServiceCollection`. I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
var client = new factory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
             {
                 builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
                 {
                     services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();
                     services.AddTransient(context => new YourController("Hello, world!"));
                 });
             }).CreateClient();
```